# Generating word library - C or C++

Tags: c++, c, performance

I need to create a simple application, but speed is very important here. Application is pretty much simple.

It will generate all available chars by saving them to text file. User will enter length that will be used for generating so the application will use recursive function with loop inside.

Will C be faster then C++ in this matter, or it does not matter?

Speed is very important because if my application needs to generate/save to file 10 million+ words.

Comment: What do you mean by "speed is very important", exactly ?

Comment: IO will be the slow part, you could write this in an interpreted language and the disk'd still slow you down.

Comment: So basically you are saying that it does not matte C or C++

Comment: If speed is important, then don't use recursion. You are copying the stack each step in the recursion. C or C++ should not matter that much. Compile with -O3, and it should be fast either way.

Comment: "speed" as in time to have the program working and bug-free (even if it takes 30 minutes for a full run) ... or "speed" as in time it takes the program to run (even if takes 3 years to have the source written)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, chances are your application will be I/O bound rather than CPU bound unless you have enough RAM to hold all that in memory.

It's much more important that you choose the best algorithm, and the best data structures to back that algorithm up.

Then implement that in the language you're most familiar with. C++ has the advantage of having easy to use containers in its standard libraries, but that's about it. You can write slow code in both, and fast code in both.